# React, BrowserRouter, Apache, and sub-directories

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app that I'm trying to deploy to a subdirectory of a site - e.g., https://example.com/myapp. The server uses Apache. I've configured package.json, BrowserRouter, and .htaccess like this:

package.json:

```
"homepage": "https://example.com/myapp/"
```

BrowserRouter:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/myapp">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

https://example.com/myapp/.htaccess:

```
FallbackResource ./index.html
```

In general, this works exactly as it should, with one major exception.

If I try https://example.com/myapp/users - that works perfectly.

However, if I try [https://example.com/myapp/user/{userId}](https://example.com/myapp/user/%7BuserId%7D), I get an error.

This is the case even though I have a route specified for that:

```
<Route path="user/:userId" element={<UserProfile />} />
```

It does work perfectly when I'm testing in Development mode at localhost:3000.

I *think* the issue is that, when the user requests https://example.com/myapp/user, Apache applies the .htaccess file in the https://example.com/myapp subdirectory.

But, when the user requests https://example.com/myapp/user/7, it's looking for a sub-sub-sub-folder that doesn't exist, doesn't find the .htaccess file, and so throws an error.

So, long story short - is there a way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Create React App [Serving apps with client side routing](https://App%20https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) docs, the `.htaccess` file in the public directory should look similar to, or contain, the following rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

This should return the root index.html file for *all* page requests into your React app.

Comment: Thanks Drew - that was exactly what I needed! I'd seen a few articles on the web that claimed to solve this, but they didn't quite work. What was needed in my case was the *QSA* flag; otherwise "deeper" links were breaking.